# Column size with datatype decimal

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datatypes

According to BOL for SQL Server 2008 R2 the data type decimal requires the following
storage bytes:

```
Precision  Storage bytes

1 - 9      =>   5

10-19      => 9

20-28      => 13

29-38      => 17
```

However, when I do a datalength() on a column that is formatted decimal(19,5) and
has the value of 10999.99999 I get back 5 bytes ? Which is according to my understanding
a precision of 10 and not of 9 and should result in 9 bytes.

this results in two questions:

1. is the size of the table with this column not depending on the column definition,
   instead the true values within the column define the table size ?
2. why is the information in BOL not matching with what datalength() returns ?

Comment: show us exact SQL please

Comment: The cutoff point for `DATALENGTH` reporting 5 or 9 bytes in this instance seems to be `42949.67295` (stored as `01 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00`) and `42949.67296` (stored as `01 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00`). Not sure how useful that behaviour is exactly!

Comment: `CREATE TABLE [Test195]( [Date] [date] NULL, [Time] [time](3) NULL, [CCYPairID] [tinyint] NULL, [Price] [decimal](19, 5) NULL, [Amount] [bigint] NULL, )`


`SELECT [Date] ,[Time] ,[CCYPairID] ,DATALENGTH([CCYPairID]) as CByte ,[Price] ,DATALENGTH([Price]) as PByte ,[Amount] ,DATALENGTH([Amount]) as AByte FROM [Test195]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't mix *storage* (5 or 9 bytes) and what you get back

In a decimal(19,5) column it is *always* 9 bytes on disk. So zero will take nine bytes.

Your `10999.99999` is merely a representation of that stored number that is then parsed as 10999.99999 by DATALENGTH

Edit:

DATALENGTH will return the number of bytes needed to store the expression given. It *ignores* datatype mostly. So `10999.99999` is treated as decimal(10,5) which *can* be stored in 5 bytes not 9 as Martin pointed out in a comment.

So a decimal(19,5) column is always 9 bytes. DATALENGTH doesn't care. It looks at the expression `10999.99999` and decides it can be stored in 5 bytes. But of course it can't

Personally, I've never used DATALENGTH except to find trailing spaces or such.

Basically, don't use [DATALENGTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) on non string datatypes.

> Returns the number of bytes used to represent any expression.
>
> DATALENGTH is especially useful with varchar, varbinary, text, image, nvarchar, and ntext data types because these data types can store variable-length data.

Note: LEN tells you how long the string representation is

```
DECLARE @i decimal(19,5)
SET @i ='10999.99999'
SELECT @i,LEN(@i),DATALENGTH(@i)
SET @i ='-90999.99999'
SELECT @i,LEN(@i),DATALENGTH(@i)
```

Comment: So you are saying that datalength() only gives me the bytes that are needed to display the given column but the actual size on disk will vary ? I did some tests with tinyint and money and there the amount of bytes did match what I would have expected according to the documentation. I'm asking these questions because I have around 13 Billion rows in a table and want to optimize the throughput even in the worst case of a full table scan. Would in this case the byte size from storage or the byte size for display matter ? (at the moment I need aprox. 15 min for a full table scan)

Comment: there is no optimisation for a full table scan. Don't focus on what an inappropriate function gives you: think of indexing or partitioning or archiving